# Boosting fields in Zend Search Lucene

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-search-lucene

When I look at the Zend framework documentation, Zend Search Lucene has the ability to boost search terms.

Is there a way to boost fields? That is, make hits in a field more relevant than others?

Example:

```
Document1
Name: Jane Doe
Description: Wife of John Doe

Document2
Name: John Doe
Description: Husband of Jane Doe

Search query = "John Doe"
```

In this example, I want to boost "Name" field because it is more relevant. The search results should list Document2 first rather than Document1

Comment: I read both Jane and John as John. Was thinking whats the difference between the 2 documents!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the [setBoost](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/Fieldable.html) method of the field. (I'm not familiar with Zend's implementation, but I assume they have an equivalent method.)

Comment: Found out that they don't have a method for this in their document field class. But upon further inspection, they do have a public boost property in that class. I don't know why they didn't make a setBoost() method for it. I guess setting them directly is ok.